# Print mdframed footnotes at bottom of page instead of after frame

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

If there is a `\footnote` inside an `mdframed` environment, then I can control, via the `footnoteinside=false` flag, whether or not I want those footnotes included inside the frame or outside. But even when typeset outside the frame, they will immediately follow the frame. Is there a way, perhaps using a small hack, to print these footnotes at the end of the (last) page where the frame was included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{footnote}
\newenvironment{mdframedwithfoot}
{   
    \savenotes
    \begin{mdframed}
    \stepcounter{footnote}
    \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
    }
{
    \end{mdframed}
    \spewnotes
}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
aa\footnote{test1}

\begin{mdframedwithfoot}
bb\footnote{test2}
\end{mdframedwithfoot}

qq

\begin{mdframed}
cc
\end{mdframed}

dd\footnote{test3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but the manual stepping of the footnote counter means that one still hase to take extra care oneself to not use more than one footnote (which will break my approach as well), and to match environment name to whether or not a footnote was used. However, using `\def\@mpfn{footnote}` I was able to avoid that explicit stepping, and `\let\thempfootnote=\thefootnote` will ensure these two always match. Did you develop this answer from a failed attempt with the `tablefootnote` package, thus answering your own comment?

Comment: @MvG I remember a similar solution that I have seen in here in tex.sx. I also had a feeling that `tablefootnote` would work :)

Comment: @cacamailg When I try to compile this, I can not compile, and get the error: `Undefined control sequence. \pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{8799518}{42674430}`.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I compiled the code above without any problem. My version is TeXLive 2015.

Comment: @cacamailg Ok, it's probably because of my TeX Live 2014.

Answer (score 15):

The standard behavior of footnotes of `mdframed` orientates on the standard behaviour of footnotes of `minipage`. `mdframed` is using the same counter.

However a simple method to prints footnotes at the bottom of the package is a minor alteration of `tablefootnote` provided by the package [`tablefootnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote):

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\makeatletter 
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdframed}{%
 \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout% 
 \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}% 
}
\makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\begin{mdframed} 
 foo\tablefootnote{foo} 
 bar\tablefootnote{bar} 
\end{mdframed} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew that was a way... :)

Comment: @cacamailg: :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found out that I could achieve the desired result by writing `\footnotemark` inside the frame and `\footnotetext{…}` after it. This had the added benefit of using a numbering scheme consistent with the rest of my document: A footnote set by `mdframed` used lower case alphabetical numbering, whereas the rest of my document used arabic numbers for footnotes. With the above approach, everything was arabic.

Comment: The footnotes of `mdframed` are equal to footnotes inside `minipage` or `tabular`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel would they work with `tablefootnote` package?

Comment: @cacamailg: It works if you add a command to the end of mdframed: `\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\makeatletter
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdframed}{%
 \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
 \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
foo \tablefootnote{foo}

bar \tablefootnote{bar}
\end{mdframed}
 
\end{document}`