# Footnotes doesn't work inside tasks

Tags: footnotes, exsheets

See the following MWE. For some reason the footnotes inside `tasks` environment are not displayed, while they work in `enumeration`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}
    \task test\footnote{test a}
\end{tasks}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test\footnote{test b}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `tasks` environment is no list (in the LaTeX sense). Every “item” is a box really. Use `\footnotemark` and outside the environment `\footnotetext`.

Comment: @cgnieder I was too lazy to look at the code of `tasks`. For me they would work as an `enumeration` list with extra features. Thanks for the solution. I think that would be easy to implement in `tasks` using the `tablefootnote` package with possible hack as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113640/print-mdframed-footnotes-at-bottom-of-page-instead-of-after-frame/113673#113673. If you want provide an answer that I will accept it.

Comment: Maybe I should make it more clear in the documentation that `{tasks}` only superficially _looks_ like a list...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I admit that [the documentation of `tasks`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tasks_en.pdf) doesn't make this fact very clear (I'll add something to the next version): the `{tasks}` environment only *looks* like a list environment because semantically it is a list. Internally it is no list in the LaTeX sense, i.e. it doesn't use a `{list}`. The main purpose of it *is not* to list it's items with a), b), ... That could be easier achieved with a customized `{enumerate}` list (e.g. via the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package). It's supposed to provide easy means to get *rows* of items rather than columns. It does this by collecting the environment body which makes it rather a *pseudo environment* and means that verbatim material cannot be used inside. It then splits the body at every occurrence of `\task` and puts the parts into boxes (or l3 coffins). These boxes are then put next to each other depending on the number of columns specified. As a consequence footnotes are no longer working inside `{tasks}`. The standard way around is using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task test\footnotemark
  \task test
  \task test
  \task test
\end{tasks}
\footnotetext{test a}

\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to load the [`footnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote) package and enable the footnotes with `\makesavenoteenv`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task test\footnote{test a}
  \task test
  \task test
  \task test
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

A third solution might be to make the `{tasks}` environment compatible with [`tablefootnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) the [same way that Marco Daniel used here for `{mdframed}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113693/5049):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\makeatletter
\AfterEndEnvironment{tasks}{%
 \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout% 
 \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}% 
}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task test\tablefootnote{test a}
  \task test
  \task test
  \task test
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm really loving `exsheets` and `tasks` for making worksheets. The horizontal layout of `tasks` seems to be what my students expect. Any plans to incorporate one of these "fixes" into the `tasks` package?