# Automatically adjusting layout of inparaenum

Tags: spacing, lists, inline

I am trying to customize an inline list in the following ways:

1. I would like an item that doesn't fit entirely on one line to be moved to the next line.
2. Increase the vertical space between consecutive lines.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Find the derivative of each of the following:\\[4pt]
\begin{inparaenum}[\hspace{1em}(a)]
\item $f_1(x)=2x^2+x-10$
\item $f_2(x)=4x^4-x^3+2x^2+5x-6$
\item $f_3(x) = -x^3-x^2+4x+6$
\item $f_4(x)=21x^5-x^4+2x^3+7x^2-13$
\item $f_5(x)=3x^4-4x^3-12x^2+12x-10$
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

So, for instance, items (c) and (e) should be on the next line. I need an environment like this when preparing problem sets for my students in which questions have multiple parts which are best laid out in this fashion. I mention this in case someone has a completely different approach.

Comment: Would you have any items that are longer/wider than the text block?

Comment: I was thinking about that, and for now, let's assume no. If an item just has to be split, other than trying to adjust margins, I don't think my problem would have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module (`zref-savepos`) can be  used to capture (x,y) coordinates of labels. Using this approach, you can gauge whether or not to break a line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69051/5764
% \zsaveposx is defined since 2011/12/05 v2.23 of zref-savepos
\@ifundefined{zsaveposy}{\let\zsaveposy\zsavepos}{}
\newcounter{vposcnt}% Vertical position counter
\renewcommand*{\thevposcnt}{vpos\number\value{vposcnt}}
\newcommand*{\markpos}{% Set current mark
  \zsaveposy{\thevposcnt M}}
\newcommand*{\leftpos}{% Set left mark
  \zsaveposy{\thevposcnt L}}
\newcommand*{\rightpos}{% Set right mark
  \zsaveposy{\thevposcnt R}}
\newcommand{\insertbreak}{%
  \zref@refused{\thevposcnt L}% Used left mark
  \zref@refused{\thevposcnt M}% Used current mark
  \zref@refused{\thevposcnt R}% Used right mark
  \ifnum\zposy{\thevposcnt M}=\zposy{\thevposcnt L}\ifnum\zposy{\thevposcnt L}=\zposy{\thevposcnt R}\relax%
  \else\par\noindent\fi\else\par\noindent\fi%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{inparaenum}\renewcommand{\theinparaenum}{(\alph{inparaenum})}
\newenvironment{inparaenum}{%
  \setcounter{inparaenum}{0}% Restart numbering
  \def\item{% How to process each item
    \ifnum\value{inparaenum}>0\rightpos\quad\fi% Place a right mark in not first item
    \stepcounter{inparaenum}\stepcounter{vposcnt}% A new item
    \markpos\ifnum\value{inparaenum}>1\insertbreak\fi%
    \leftpos\theinparaenum\space\ignorespaces}%
  \noindent\ignorespaces}%
  {\rightpos}% End inparaenum with right mark
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Find the derivative of each of the following: \par\medskip
\begin{inparaenum}
  \item $f_1(x)=2x^2+x-10$
  \item $f_2(x)=4x^4-x^3+2x^2+5x-6$
  \item $f_3(x)=-x^3-x^2+4x+6$
  \item $f_4(x)=21x^5-x^4+2x^3+7x^2-13$
  \item $f_5(x)=3x^4-4x^3-12x^2+12x-10$
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

If there's any shift in the vertical position, you'll have to recompile until references settle.

If need be, one could include a check for an `inparaenum` without an `\item`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. How would I go about adjusting the vertical space between each line automatically?

Comment: @DJJerome: Within `\insertbreak` there are two uses of `\par`. You can change these to `\par\medskip` or, more generally, `\par\vspace{<len>}` for a gap of length `<len>`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative suggestion (since you mention completely different approaches…). The `tasks` package (part of my [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) bundle) provides a list-like environment (well, [not *exactly* list-like](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121807/5049)...) for list layouts in columns with items placed in rows rather than columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
  counter-format = (tsk[a]) ,% labels (a) (b) ...
  label-width    = 2em
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Find the derivative of each of the following:
\begin{tasks}(2)% <= use two columns, the default number can be set with an option, too
  \task $f_1(x)=2x^2+x-10$
  \task $f_2(x)=4x^4-x^3+2x^2+5x-6$
  \task $f_3(x)=-x^3-x^2+4x+6$
  \task $f_4(x)=21x^5-x^4+2x^3+7x^2-13$
  \task $f_5(x)=3x^4-4x^3-12x^2+12x-10$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]