# Uniformly itemize list in two columns throughout the document

Tags: lists, two-column, itemize

How can I get lists arranged in two columns throughout the document. I would like to make changes only in preamble and not in the list.

I am thinking of this structure

. First item    . second item

. third item

Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kindly note the horizontal sequence 1-2 Next line-3 and 4. Also changes should be in the preamble so that I can simply use \begin{itemize} \item \end{itemize} in main text. Can this be done using wikienvironment ?

Comment: Just to be sure, would you accept a `\newcommand` approach? Like `\newcommand{\bmyitemize}{\begin{multicols}{2}\begin{itemize}}` 
 and `\newcommand{\emyitemize}{\end{itemize}\end{multicols}}` ? Or do you _want_ to use `\begin{itemize}` and end throughout?

Comment: would prefer \begin{itemize} \end{itemize}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put these lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\begin{multicols}{2}}    
\AtEndEnvironment{itemize}{\end{multicols}}
```

This will change all `itemize` environments in to two columns (assuming that is what you want).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\begin{multicols}{2}}    %%% this line
\AtEndEnvironment{itemize}{\end{multicols}}            %%% and this one
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}        
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As egreg notes, you can use a `newenvironment` so that normal `itemize` is still available:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
\begin{itemize}
\begin{multicols}{2}
}{%
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\end{myitemize}
Some other text.
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `enumitem` too, you can define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet,before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
after=\end{multicols}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd create a new environment, rather than changing the default `itemize` that would be lost.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you want to try the [`multienum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multenum) package.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}

\newenvironment{multiitem}{%
  \multienumerate\renewcommand{\labelname}{\textbullet}%
}{%
  \endmultienumerate%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multiitem}
\mitemxx{1}{2}
\mitemxx{3}{4}
\mitemxx{5}{6}
\mitemxx{7}{8}
\mitemxx{9}{10}
\end{multiitem}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> I am thinking of this structure
>
> . First item . second item
>
> . third item

You might like the `tasks` package (part of the [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) bundle).  It provides a list-like structure similar to the one you outlined. (They're not really lists in the LaTeX sense of `{list}` or `{trivlist}`, see the manual for details.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}

% new list-like environment
% \NewTasks[options]{name}[separator](default number of columns)
\NewTasks[style=itemize]{myitemize}[\item](2)

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% insert text fragments
\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{myitemize}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
  \item four
  \item five
  \item six
  \item seven
  \item eight
  \item nine
\end{myitemize}

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, didn't try this package of yours before, +1.

Comment: @karlkoeller I always a bit reluctant of recommending this package as it [has some drawbacks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121807/5049).