# Tasks in custom Environment

Tags: environments, tasks

I need to wrap a `tasks` environment inside a custom `\NewEnviron`. Apparently, `tasks` chokes on code besides its `\task` or `\item` due to the [way it handles its own environment body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121754/footnotes-doesnt-work-inside-tasks), presumably causing it to do so on `\BODY`. Any way to get around this? Exact error given is "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing `\item`", as per:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}

\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[1]),label-width=2ex]{mytaskenum}[\item](3)
\NewEnviron{mytaskenv}[1][Exercises]{
  % Misc. stuff to precede the tasks env here
  \begin{mytaskenum}
  \BODY
  \end{mytaskenum}
  % Misc. stuff to follow
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytaskenv}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{mytaskenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @clemens `\BODY` is provided by `environ`; it expands to the contents of what's between `\begin{mytaskenv}` and `\end{mytaskenv}`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: `tasks` needs to see the expansion of the macro `\BODY` in order to do its work

Comment: Is there a simple way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to expand `\BODY` before `\begin{mytaskenum}` starts its job:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}

\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[1]),label-width=2ex]{mytaskenum}[\item](3)
\NewEnviron{mytaskenv}[1][Exercises]{%
  % Misc. stuff to preceed the tasks env here
  \def\tempbegin{\begin{mytaskenum}}%
  \expandafter\tempbegin\BODY
  \end{mytaskenum}
  % Misc. stuff to follow
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytaskenv}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{mytaskenv}

Check:

\begin{mytaskenum}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{mytaskenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Cleaner alternative with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[1]),label-width=2ex]{mytaskenum}[\item](3)

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\domytaskenum}{}
 {
  \texman_mytaskenum:V \BODY
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \texman_mytaskenum:n #1
 {
  \begin{mytaskenum}
  #1
  \end{mytaskenum}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \texman_mytaskenum:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewEnviron{mytaskenv}[1][Exercises]{%
  % Misc. stuff to preceed the tasks env here
  \domytaskenum
  % Misc. stuff to follow
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mytaskenv}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{mytaskenv}

Check:

\begin{mytaskenum}
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
  \item item 3
\end{mytaskenum}

\end{document}
```

The `\domytaskenum` command simply calls `\texman_domytaskenum:V \BODY`; in turn `\texman_domytaskenum:V` is a variant of `\texman_domytaskenum:n` that does the job of processing the argument in the `mytaskenum` environment. The `V` variant uses the value of the token list stored in `\BODY` as if it was the explicit contents. Basically it does the same trick as before, but in a more abstract way, without doing the temporary definition.

Comment: Can you get this to work an xparse NewDocumentEnvironment rather than a environ environment? I am trying to get this to work for more than one optional argument.

Comment: @Pravin More than one optional arguments make for awkward syntax; please, make a new question with the desired specifications.

Comment: please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391459/nesting-tasks-within-an-xparse-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1