# wrap around task environment not working

Tags: environments, xparse, tasks

I am trying to create an environment wrapping a `task` environment (from the `tasks` package). To build the new environment I am using the `xparse` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasks[%
counter-format=tsk[a]),
item-indent=0pt,
after-item-skip=0pt,
%label-offset=0.1em
]{aaaa}


\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{bbbb}{}
{%
    \begin{aaaa}
}{%
    \end{aaaa}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{bbbb}
  \task first
  \task secod
\end{bbbb}
\end{document}
```

But when I compile I got the error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: \begin{aaaa} on input line 23 ended by \end{bbbb}.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 \end{bbbb}
```

It seems that tne `\DeclareDocumentEnvironemnt` is not working fine in this case.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of (or at least related to) http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237230/

Comment: Won't compile even with `aaaa` for the `bbbb` because `\tasklabelwidth` is undefined. Changing that, it still won't compile with `aaaa` due to a missing `\item`. Note that this is true even if you give it an `\item`. So there is really not much hope of this working even without the added complication of a wrapper.

Comment: @cfr the reasons why are explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121807/

Comment: @clemens Why did they have to pick `l`? Every single time, I read `l3` as `13`.

Comment: @clemens I can't vote your answer there up again because the system remembers me from before. My point was really that a basic sanity check is always good to run before posting an MWE online. I can't say how many times something which I positively *knew* worked didn't work at all. Usually because of some completely other thing which I entirely overlooked due to a focus on the bit which I *positively, certainly 100% knew must* be the problem.

Comment: @cfr Sorry for the errors. Now it compiles when using the `aaaa` environment directly but not the `bbbb`.

Comment: @clemens. I checked the answer of (tex.stackexchange.com/q/237230). But still don't know what to expand or do. I would like to use `xparse` to define the new environment, so there is no \BODY command as in the other question.

Comment: @TeXtnik you can't avoid `environ` I'm afraid: `tasks` *needs* to read the environment body as argument before it arranges the items

Comment: Could you tell us why you wish to avoid the use of `\BODY`? Perhaps there's another way to achieve what you want to do.