# Format tasks like (a) instead of a) globally

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, tasks

I am still relatively new at Latex, but I have exhausted this site, list/enumerate/task documentation, and many other googled resources.  Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

I have a need to create numbered lists and alphabetic lists.  I need these lists to be column friendly (i.e., I need to be able to format into columns quickly/easily).  I have been using \NewTasks with great success in the article class with enumerate and itemize, but I am unable to get the (a) (b) formatting I desire.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,mathtools,flexisym,tasks,enumitem,multicol,mdframed,tabularx,tasks}

%my itemized lists in two columns - these work very well for bullets and numbering
\NewTasks[style=enumerate]{myitemize}[\item](2)
\NewTasks[style=enumerate]{item3}[\item](3)
\NewTasks[style=itemize]{itemnew}[\aitem](2)

% this works well for giving me one column of items labeled the way I want
%it labeled, but as soon as I try to get two columns going like
% (a) blah      (b) blah 
% (c) blah      (d) blah
% it doesn't work and will number vertically first.
\newlist{alphalist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[alphalist,1]{label={(\alph*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2) %this is what I want, but with (a) labels!!
\task task 1
\task task 2
\task task 3
\end{tasks}

\begin{itemnew} % I am just trying things, I don't want/need bulleted lists
\aitem hi2
\aitem hi2
\end{itemnew}

\begin{enumerate}
\item this is in one column
\item because this problem is worked horizontally
\end{enumerate}

\begin{myitemize}(2)
\item but these problems
\item are in two columns
\item because they are better
\item when worked vertically
\end{myitemize}

\begin{multicols}{2} % wrong order of labels
\begin{alphalist}
\item but these problems
\item are in two columns
\item because they are better
\item when worked vertically
\end{alphalist}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[Tasks in custom Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237230/tasks-in-custom-environment?rq=1) << this is so close!!  I can get it to be (1) and (2) in the way I want, but not (a) and (b).  I am running out of hair to pull out.  I know I am missing something simple (or at least I hope it's simple).

In summary, I am hoping to get the tasks list to be labeled as (\alph) instead of \alph) and I have no idea how to do that.  I can do this in the exam class (with {parts} and {choices}), but there HAS to be something in the article class for this, right?? The notes I am writing up are already in the article class... Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am happy to clarify if needed.  Thank you for your time and patience!

Edit:  Well, I might have submitted a question too soon.  Adding the following to the preamble seems to work although it doesn't seem like the most efficient way?  Or maybe it is.  I'd still like to know if there's a way to globally change the format of the "tasks" environment.

```
\newlist{mparts}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mparts]{label*=(\alph*)}
\newcommand{\mpart}{\item}

\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
after=\end{multicols}}

\SetEnumitemKey{threecol}{
 before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{3},
 after=\end{multicols}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If just somebody would write a [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks-manual.pdf) for `tasks`, heh?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\DeclareInstance{tasks}{alphabetize-parens}{default}{
  counter-format = { (tsk[a]) },
  label-width    = 1.333em,
}

\settasks{style=alphabetize-parens}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2) %this is what I want, but with (a) labels!!
\task task 1
\task task 2
\task task 3
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]