# Nesting Tasks within an xparse Environment

Tags: environments, xparse, tasks

I need to use xparse as I am passing multiple optional arguments through a custom environment (not shown here for brevity). When I attempt to pass the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newlength{\longlabel}
\settowidth{\longlabel}{(m)}
\NewTasks[label-format=\color{blue}, counter-format={(tsk[a])}, label-width=\longlabel,
    item-indent=0pt, label-offset=2pt, column-sep={10pt}, before-skip=-8pt, after-item-skip=2pt, after-skip=-4pt]{newTask}[\item]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{dummyEnvironment}{}
  {\begin{newTask}(2)}
  {\end{newTask}}

\begin{document}

\begin{newTask}(2)
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \end{newTask}

\begin{dummyEnvironment}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \end{dummyEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

An error returns stating that `\begin{newTasks}` is ended by `\end{dummyEnvironment}`

Error:

```
C:\Users... LaTeX Error: \begin{newTask} on input line 22 ended by \end{dummyEnvironment}. [^^I\end{dummyEnvironment}]
C:\Users... LaTeX Error: \begin{dummyEnvironment} on input line 22 ended by \end{document}. [\end{document}]
```

Now this question has been answered before for the `environ' package [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237230/tasks-in-custom-environment), but how would you fix this problem using xparse environments?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to pass multiple optional arguments through environ, so to enable https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237230/tasks-in-custom-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1 to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (in fact, as egreg comments below, you **should**) use `\newtask...\endnewtask` directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newlength{\longlabel}
\settowidth{\longlabel}{(m)}
\NewTasks[label-format=\color{blue}, counter-format={(tsk[a])}, label-width=\longlabel,
    item-indent=0pt, label-offset=2pt, column-sep={10pt}, before-skip=-8pt, after-item-skip=2pt, after-skip=-4pt]{newTask}[\item]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{dummyEnvironment}{}
  {\newTask(2)}
  {\endnewTask}

\begin{document}

\begin{newTask}(2)
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \end{newTask}

\begin{dummyEnvironment}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \end{dummyEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

When you open an environment with `\begin{newtask}...\end{newtask}` what happens is that a new tex-group is opened, using `\bgroup` or `\begingroup` (I can't remember which), and `\newtask` is called. Latex then looks ahead for a matching `\end{newtask}` whereupon it inserts `\endnewtask` and closes the group. With the `dummyEnvironment` in the OP, latex sees a `\begin{newtask}` and so looks ahead for a matching `\end{newtask}`. Unfortunately, it can't find this because the `\end{newtask}` is hidden in `\end{dummyEnvironment}`, which it sees first. This is why the code in the OP gives an error. By using `\newtask....\endnewtask` you avoid this issue.

For completeness, here is the output:

[image]

Comment: The fact is that `newTask` is defined in terms of `\NewEnviron`, so the standard method for dealing with environments defined upon it is to use `\newTask...\endnewTask`. The first verb in your answer should be *should* rather than *can*.

Comment: Wow, what an excellent answer. Thank you both very much!!