# How do you place text in a box without capturing footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, backgrounds

I would like to place a light grey box behind paragraphs, or groups of paragraphs (which might include quotes, lists, etc...).  Unfortunately `mdframed` captures the footnotes and brings them into the grey box. My attempt at `\colorbox` results in the footnote disappearing.

So is there a way to place colour behind paragraphs/lists/quotes and so on, without impacting footnoting?

---

**Update:** A the request of Teepeemm, here is a sample minimal document that I don't know how to update to apply a grey box in a way that won't interfere with the footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is some text and this is is some more
text.\footnote{This is a footnote} And here
is some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you gave us a minimal working example that we could start from.

Comment: Yes I know there is that person who wants to tell me to provide sample code. However, the problem is I don't know which approach has even the potential to become a working solution. None of them work as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Teepeemm What would you like? A sample document with some plain text? Or a sample document showing how to use mdframed? A sample on how to use colorbox? None of them work as far as I can tell

Comment: Though not ideal, `\footnotemark` inside and then `\footnotetext{...}` outside the mdframed env works I think. Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113640/117534?

Comment: I would argue not a duplicate. That other question requires `mdframed`. This question just asks how to add a background colour by any means possible (without footnote interruption)

Comment: @Jacob You have an example with mdframed, where the footnote gets captured.  And an example with colorbox where the footnote disappears.  An example with both would be a good starting part. --- I don't understand you disputing the duplicate: you are looking for any means possible, of which mdframed is one means.

Comment: I am disputing the duplicate, because I am not asking how to solve a problem inherent with `mdframed`. I just want to work out how to add backgrounds.  If people would like to see how mdframed works they can surely refer to the post you reference for details, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113693/4736) (thanks to [Troy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117534/troy)), it seems to be easy to have footnotes in a mdframe-box and I guess, this question really is a duplicate...

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{mdframed} 
\usepackage{tablefootnote, blindtext} 
\makeatletter 
\AfterEndEnvironment{mdframed}{%
 \tfn@tablefootnoteprintout% 
 \gdef\tfn@fnt{0}% 
}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
This is some text and this is is some more
text.\footnote{This is a footnote} And here
is some text.
\begin{mdframed} 
 This is  text inside the frame\tablefootnote{foo} 
 and some more text inside the frame\tablefootnote{bar}.
\end{mdframed}

This is some text and this is is some more
text.\footnote{This is the laaaaast footnote} And here
is some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is fine for a short box, but for a longer box all footnotes are placed on the final page of the box.